# Conditional WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, condition

I have, from what I can tell, a unique question. I would like to know if there's a way to construct a query in which the existence of the actual where clause itself is conditional.

I'm writing a stored procedure where I would like to pass in a filter (e.g. `Col1=1 or Col2=3`) and my query looks something like the following:

```sql
set @filter = 'Col1=1 or Col2=3' --assume these variables have been declared already
select * from @tbl where @filter --I need to use a table variable
```

**Note**: I tried using `sp_executesql` and `sp_sqlexec` but neither take a table variable. I would also like to avoid using an `if-else` statement. Please do not suggest either of these as your answer. :)

Comment: Why do you need to use table variable? Could you not use a temp table instead?

Comment: Can you explain why "I would also like to avoid using an if-else statement".

Comment: I probably should have stated that I would LIKE to use a table variable because I prefer to keep my SQL clean rather than dealing with a bunch of temp table cleanup and if-else statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic SQL won't be able to see your table variable unless you also declare it and populate it within the same dynamic SQL scope. A #temp table will work fine, and I'm not sure why you "need" to use a table variable, but you can always do this:

```
SELECT * INTO #tbl FROM @tbl;
```

Anyway assuming you can change your process:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(Col1 INT, Col2 INT);

INSERT #tbl SELECT 1,4
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,3
  UNION ALL SELECT 5,8;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @filter NVARCHAR(255);

SET @sql = N'SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM #tbl';

SET @filter = N'Col1 = 1 OR Col2 = 3';

SET @sql = @sql + COALESCE(' WHERE ' + @filter, '');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

Results:

```
Col1        Col2
----------- -----------
1           4
2           3
```

As an aside, you *cannot* do things like this:

```
select * from @tbl where @filter
```

You need to build such statements dynamically. SQL Server won't see @tbl or @filter as entities or where clauses.

Comment: Brilliant use of `COALESCE`! I would have never thought of that. :) I also added `set @filter = nullif(@filter,'')` just before that to ensure an empty string is never passed in which would create an invalid SQL statement. I also `if object_id(N'tempdb..#tbl') is not null drop table #tbl` before the #tbl create to ensure I'm starting with a clean slate.

Answer (score 2):

sp_executesql works just fine with table variables.  You just need to create a user defined table type first.

```
CREATE TYPE IdTable TABLE AS (Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::IdTable TO PUBLIC

GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @tableVar IdTable

INSERT INTO @tableVar (3)

SET @sql = N'Select id from @p1 where ' + @filter

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, '@p1 IdTable readonly', @p1=@tableVar
```

Comment: The question is about SQL Server 2005 and user defined table types was introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that this was for sql 2005.  Aaron Bertrand's answer above is your best bet.

Comment: @StrayCatDBA For future reference, would this create a permanent defined type in the database? Server? Thanks for the answer anyway! :)